# Mix Shader not mixing textures

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I have two different textures with selected geometry on both to properly display textures on the mountain (pictures of node tree and results right below this)
[image]
[image]

I'm trying to mix them both with a mix shader with a node tree plugged in to the factor of a mix shader after that to make the top of the mountain the snow/rock texture and the bottom of the mountain the grass/rock texture (by making the top of the mountain transparent by a transparent BSDF node plugged into the bottom of the mix shader) the result in and of itself is working perfectly. Node tree and result pictured below.
[image]
[image]

I then have both of these mixed with a mix shader and it appears on the mountain as pink (basically it doesn't work.) Why is this happening? I'll be glad to answer any questions!
[image]

Here's a picture of the complete node setup!
[image]

And here's a picture of the node setup that is turning it pink!
[image]

Comment: You might run out of memory, you could try switching to the cpu.

Comment: I'm on the CPU but since this is a far-away object, I am using 1K textures so it's only using a little over 1 GB

Comment: Hey :). There used to be some limits on number of textures in Eevee. Does it work im Cycles? Or when rendered?

Comment: No it does not.